# kubernetes RPC micro-service with API gateway

Tags: kubernetes, rpc, aws-api-gateway

I use RPC protocol app as a micro-service
and an API Gateway in front of them as a proxy.

Now I want to use k8s to deploy micro-service, the API gateway is out of k8s cluster, RPC micro-service is deployed by k8s, there are three replicas RPC micro-service in my cluster.

My question is how could I directly access k8s's pod, because I must build a connection pool to hold these connections, for example, I have three RPC micro-service pod.

this is my architecture
[architecture image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpQZd.png)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't consume your RPC micro-service from a pod directly but through a Kubernetes service.

First, you have to expose your RPC as a public K8S service, that will provide you a port where it is listening. With the IP of the cluster (can be more than one, of course) and that port, you will be able to consume your RPC micro-service.

Check the docs to learn how to expose it:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

You can access a pod directly using `hostNetwork` configuration parameter. However, Kubernetes doesn't recommend it: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/

If you need to keep a shared session or something like that between your replicas, I would use another external component like Redis or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I exposed the RPC as a public K8S service, and set the Session Affinity to ClientIP。

when my API Gateway access the k8s service, only one pod response, because the session is affinity, the two other pods never used